# Mongo DB Schema arrange and get correct data from nested array in search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning backend coding

I am using single collection to data save to db
Collection name is **book** , each book has few nested arrays (like category and may be sub categories )

I have to show all categories title of each books in client side in **category search** scenario.

```
book = [
          {
            name: '';
            ----------
            ----------
            category:[
                      {
                         title: ''
                      }
                      ----------
                      ----------
            ]
          }
       ]
```

How to find and get data using mongoose ?
Do I have to create separate collection for nested arrays ? is that right way?

```
   // Get all category
    exports.Allcategory = function(req, res){        
        Book.find({}, function(err, category){
            if (err) return res.json({message: 'Error on the server!', status: 500 });
            return res.json(category); 
        });
    };
```

Comment: depends upon your requirements. do you ever need categories or any other property from the nested array?

Comment: Yes ... Now I have to show categories name , How can I achieve that

Comment: So, your schema is already designed? Or you want to design? If already designed, can you share your schema?

Comment: @Hunter, on client side, you just want to show `Category Name` or entire `Book Collection`?

Comment: Category names from all books , Each book has different categories @MalikAwan

Comment: @Hunter if you need the nested properties separately also then better keep the separate schemas for each entity and do your joins whenever needed while sending data to the client.

Comment: If you want to keep the same schema and need only categories you can use   `Book.find({}, {category: 1}, ()....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Backend code, you are sending whole document of Book, not just category array. 
In your case this approach will be like this.

```
Books.map(item => 
 {item.name}  // this will print book name. in this iteration you can get any property defined at this level
     {item.category.map(c => ){
     {c.title} //this will print category name
}}    
){

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Malik , Can I practise this way ? or
 Do I have to create separate collection If I want to get data from each book?

Comment: No need to create any separate collection. see my edit answer.